# Deploy ShinyProxy and an application with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, shinyapps, shinyproxy

I'm trying to deploy a ShinyProxy in a Docker container to Azure. Also, I have the ShinyApp repositories in Azure DevOps. Every time a developer updates the code in a repository, I want to the CD/CI deploy the new code creating a Docker container to Azure.

Also, I think, I have to create an internal Docker network between the ShinyProxy and the app.

How can I create this process? Is there any tutorial how to setup a pipeline in Azure DevOps and run a ShinyProxy on Azure?

Comment: Hi @Enrico, how are things going? Is my suggestion helpful to you? Please have a try with it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and study, I found how to create a full end-to-end deployment. I have created a complete step-by-step guide in [my blog](https://www.puresourcecode.com/programming-languages/r/deploy-shinyapps-with-azure-and-docker/).

I hope it could help other guys.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to deploy your app to **Azure Container Registry**?

If so, below are the main steps you need to do:

1. Create a container registry on the **Azure Portal**.
2. Create a [**Docker registry service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) on the project settings to enable your pipeline to push images into the container registry.
3. Create the pipeline that gets source from your repository.
4. Add the [**Docker task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) in the pipeline,

   - select the **Docker registry service connection** created in above step as the '**`Container registry`**'.
   - select '**`buildAndPush`**' as the '**`command`**'.

To view more details, you can reference to "[**Build and push to Azure Container Registry**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops)".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm using Azure Registry. My issue is related to ShinyProxy because I have to deploy the ShinyProxy and the app in 2 different container and then create a network between them. Generally speaking, ShinyProxy serves more than one ShinyApp.

Comment: Hi @Enrico, you can try to set up the container job (or service containers) in your pipeline. The containers you set on a job are networked together so that they can reach each other by their services name. To view more details, you can see "[**Define container jobs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops)" and "[**Service containers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".